# Is it possible to save an NSMutableArray to disk in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray

Is it possible to save an NSMutableArray to disk in iOS? If so how would you go about it?

I've tried the following with no success.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist" ];
[assets writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

My NSMutableArray consists of ALAssets of photos and videos retrieved from the ALAssetsLibrary as follows:

```
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) { if (result) { [assets addObject:result]; } };
```

Comment: There are several ways to save the array itself to disk, but saving the objects it addresses is a different matter -- depends on the type of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as bellow

```
NSMutableArray *assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *aDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [aDict setValue:@"Rajesh" forKey:@"Name"];
    [aDict setValue:@"India" forKey:@"Country"];
    [assets addObject:aDict];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist" ];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:assets toFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *assetsBack = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%@", assetsBack);
```

Comment: that didn't work either. I'm still getting the follow error.           "-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 89 beyond bounds for empty array'"

Comment: I have create sample project and check it it is working fine at my end can you provide error?

Comment: My NSMutableArray consists of ALAssets of photos and videos retrieved from the ALAssetsLibrary as follows:  ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        
        if (result) {
            [assets addObject:result];
        }
    };